# Зачем в BitVector32 используется как int, так и uint?

Tags: c#, .net, типы-данных, int

Разбираю [BitVector32](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/bitvector32.cs,f4992bfe6af24ac2). Возник такой вопрос: зачем смешивают использование int и uint? В том же самом конструкторе, например.

```
private uint data;

/// <devdoc>
/// <para>Initializes a new instance of the BitVector32 structure with the specified internal data.</para>
/// </devdoc>
public BitVector32(int data) {
    this.data = (uint)data;
}
```

Почему нельзя передать сразу в виде uint значение?

Я предполагаю, что это связано с выравниванием памяти. Так ли это?

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под *смешиванием в конструкторе*? У `BitVector32` [два конструктора](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.-ctor?view=netcore-2.2) — с параметром типа `int` и параметром типа `BitVector32`. Конструктора с параметром `uint` там нет.

Comment: Параметр первого конструктора имеет тип int, однако значение типа int приводится к uint и присваивается полю data. Под смешиванием я понимаю именно данное.

Comment: Понял, о каком смешивании речь. Значение хранится в виде `uint` потому что битовые операции удобно выполнять с беззнаковыми целыми. В знаковых целых знак хранится в старшем бите, и число неожиданно может стать положительным из отрицательного и наоборот. Но во всех методах и свойствах, доступных снаружи, нельзя использовать `uint`, потому что это не CLS-совместимый тип. Подробнее о CLS-совместимости см. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/language-independence-and-language-independent-components#cls-compliance-rules

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Так это же ответ. Зачем его публиковать как комментарий?

Comment: Только нужно дополнить про uint внутри. Дело не в "удобности", а в том, что BitVector32 предназначен для хранения логического значения, а не числового. При этом операция сдвига int и long в .NET [арифметическая](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators), а в данном типе очевидно, нужна именно логическая, потому и uint внутри. Для других операций, в общем-то не важно, какой тип использовать.